# Fourier transform on a regular lattice: The restricted set of wave-vectors

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform, periodic-functions

I) Consider a function defined only on the vertices of a 1D regular lattice: $f_i \equiv f(x_i)$ for all $x_i$, $i \in \{ 1, 2, ..., N \}$ and $x_{i+1} - x_i = a$, where $a > 0$ is the “lattice spacing”.

The discrete Fourier transform (DFT) of the function is defined as
$$
\tilde{f}(k) = \sum_{x_i} f(x_i)  e^{- \mathrm{i} k  x_i}  \quad\quad (1)
$$
where k is the wave-vector; the inverse DFT reads
$$
f(x_i) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{k} \tilde{f}(k) e^{\mathrm{i} k x_i}   \quad\quad (2)
$$
If $f$ is **periodic** with periodicity $Na$, that is $f(x_i + Na) = f(x_i)$, then the allowed k-values are
$$
k_m = \frac{2\pi m}{Na}, m \in \mathbb{Z}   \quad\quad (3)
$$

Furthermore, since $f(k_m) = f(k_m + 2\pi/a)$, it is sufficient to consider $k_m$ with $m = 0, 1, ..., N - 1$; that is, wave-vectors are restricted to the “first Brillouin zone” (1BZ).

II) Consider the situation where the function $f$ is defined on $x_i$ and $x_i + b$ for all $x_i$, $i \in \{1, 2, \cdots, N\}$, where, as before, $x_{i+1} - x_i = a$, and $0 < b < a$.

$f$ is still **periodic** with periodicity $Na$, that is $f(x_i + Na) = f(x_i)$, therefore, the allowed k-values are $k_m = \frac{2\pi m}{Na}, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, as before.
Yet, in contrast to case I), $f(k_m) \neq f(k_m + 2\pi/a)$ and hence, the wave-vectors are *not* restricted to the 1BZ.

[image]

*Question*: Is it still possible in case II) to find a countably-finite “restricted” set of k-values as in case I)?

Comment: Your equation $(1)$ isn't a discrete Fourier transform. It yields a continuous function of $k$, whereas a discrete Fourier transform yields a finite sequence of values. Your equation $(2)$ makes no sense, since you're summing over a continuous variable $k$.

Comment: If $f$ is periodic (as it is in this question), the $k$-set becomes discrete. @joriki